# How to prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} (1+xy)^{\left(\frac{1}{|x|+|y|}\right)} = 1$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I know that $ xy \leqslant|x|+|y|$. And because $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} 1^{\left(\frac{1}{|x|+|y|}\right)} = 1$, I say that the inside goes faster to $1$, than the exponent goes to infinity.

But that doesnt seem mathematically correct to me (or is it?). What would be the correct mathematical proof to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ then we have
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} (1+xy)^{(\frac{1}{|x|+|y|})} =
\lim_{r\to(0)} (1+r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta))^{(\frac{1}{r(|\sin(\theta)|+|\cos(\theta)|)})}
$$
$$
={\lim_{r\to(0)} (1+r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta))^\frac{1}{r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}}^{(\frac{r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{r(|\sin(\theta)|+|\cos(\theta)|)})}
$$
$$
={\lim_{r\to(0)}}{e}^{r(\frac{\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{(|\sin(\theta)|+|\cos(\theta)|)})}=e^0=1
$$
There are two notes. First, the limit of $0$ in the bounded function is zero and the second, the relation $|\sin(\theta)|+|\cos(\theta)|$ is not zero at the same $\theta$.

Comment: Would you mind explaining/expanding what you did in third step? I see you have extended it by function from inside and than powering it to e, but I don't see why that extended fraction disappeared

Comment: @wutter It is a classical Technic that is as follows 
$$
\lim_{x\to(0)}(1+f(x))^{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to(0)}{(1+f(x))^{(\frac{1}{f(x)})}}^{f(x)g(x)}
=\lim_{x\to(0)}e^{f(x)g(x)}
$$ 
Where $\lim_{x\to(0)}f(x)=0$. See for more details [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))

Comment: @wutter I suggest you for solving the limit with two variable first use the polar method.